# Configure Tomcat to use a trust store other than cacerts

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, https, webclient

I'm running Tomcat 6 on Windows and would like to have Tomcat use a different trust store other than cacerts for Java client web requests. I've tried adding this setting:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\ca.keystore"
```

To the registry in key:

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Tomcat6\Parameters\Java
```

That doesn't seem to work though. It still uses the JRE cacerts store. Our Java code makes web requests to HTTPS endpoints and I would like to keep the certificates in a key store other than the JRE one because it gets removed when java is uninstalled/updated.

Comment: Considering the discussions, this question should be "Configure the JRE (in which I'm running Tomcat) [... but that only matters as far as the Tomcat installer is concerned ...] to use a trust store other than the default".

Comment: @Bruno No because the solution is specific to Tomcat. See the registry key.

Comment: Sure, I'm just saying the question could be clarified (and it belongs to ServerFault anyway, btw), since "configuring Tomcat" usually refers to configuring its connectors and the container itself. Here you're after a configuration that spans the whole JRE.

Comment: @Bruno Yep, I agree Server Fault is a better home. It's an old question, but I wanted to put the solution in case it helps someone else. It did help a [couple folks](http://www.coderanch.com/t/529157/Tomcat/Configure-Tomcat-trust-store-other) over at java ranch.

Comment: @cone If Tomcat has a startup script on the Mac you would specify these Java initialization parameters in the startup script.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out I was missing `trustStorePassword`. Here is the solution:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Tomcat6\Parameters\Java 

-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\ca.keystore" 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="password"
```

**Update**: There seems to be some confusion in some of the comments here between what this setting and `truststoreFile` from `server.xml` do. I created a [blog entry](http://andyarismendi.blogspot.com/2012/01/changing-tomcats-ca-trust-keystore-file.html) to explain the problem (in great detail) and how this solution addresses it and why the changing `server.xml` does not.

Comment: EJP's answer was correct, wasn't it? Usually you specify the trust store (and its password) in the connector configuration (although it will fall back to the global `javax.net.ssl.trustStore*` settings indeed).

Comment: @Bruno No, not in server.xml. This must be done the registry! The two are used for different purposes. This is for the JVM.

Comment: Ah, your question is a bit confusing though. The title and the beginning talks about Tomcat, and you only mention at the end that your application is in fact a client (as far as the trust store is concerned).

Comment: @Bruno Tomcat is running on the JVM. In order to change Tomcat's behavior for this problem the configuration needs to be done to the JVM. This change only affects the JVM running Tomcat.

Comment: Agreed. The confusion only comes from the fact that it's not about configuring Tomcat, but its launcher, which runs the JRE, which in turns runs Tomcat. You're right it makes sense from the end of your question, but a clearer title and beginning might have given you an answer sooner :-)

Comment: @AndyArismendi The two are not used for different purposes. You have discovered an *additional* mechanism.

Comment: @AndyArismendi, your question (and your blog post) are still a bit confusing, because you're talking about configuring Tomcat, not the JVM running it or its webapps. Configuring Tomcat usually refers to is its connectors settings (also affected by the global settings). However, what you were really after is configuring the trust store used by the webapps within Tomcat, not really Tomcat itself (a problem you've solved by setting the parameters for the whole JVM where Tomcat is running, via its launcher). That's quite ambiguous at best, since it's not Tomcat as such that you're configuring.

Comment: @Bruno Yes, you have it right, it's a global change for all Tomcat webapps. I would still call it configuring Tomcat though. The little applet I [screenshotted](http://lh6.ggpht.com/-aZnfOrJhjt4/TwkupiU27oI/AAAAAAAACbk/FiUErQis_rA/image_thumb%25255B54%25255D.png?imgmax=800) in the blog where I set the Djavax settings is even called "Configure Tomcat" in the Windows start menu :-) Since Tomcat and the JVM act together to provide a web server i'm really using the term Tomcat in that collective sense.